# Why is the printf statement not printing even after the conditions of 201 is met in MPI Leader election code

Tags: mpi, openmpi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, size, uid, recv;
    int round = 1;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    uid = (rand() * (rank + 1) * size) % 100;
    if (uid < 0)
        uid = uid + 100;
    int next, prev;
    MPI_Status st;

    // next & prev
    next = (rank == size - 1 ? 0 : rank + 1);
    prev = (rank == 0 ? size - 1 : rank - 1);
    
    printf("Entry --> Rank :%d, with uid %d \n", rank, uid);
    MPI_Send(&uid, 1, MPI_INT, next, round, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    while (1)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, MPI_INT, prev, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);

        if (st.MPI_TAG == 201)
        {
            // printf("leader is elected");
            // MPI_Send(&recv, 1, MPI_INT,next,201,MPI_COMM_WORLD );
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,201);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            round = st.MPI_TAG;
            printf("Round %d Rank :%d, with uid %d \n", round, rank, uid);
            if (recv == uid)
            {
                printf("Leader is-->  %d",rank);
                // printf("I am the leader...Rank %d\n", rank);
                MPI_Send(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, next, 201, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                break;
            }
            if (recv > uid)
            {
                MPI_Send(&recv, 1, MPI_INT, next, round + 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

In the first image line 43 is not printed.
[image]

In second image if i comment line 43 and uncomment line 44 it is printed.
[image]

though i can infer that \n is the deciding factor, is it a bug or i am doing something wrong??

I am using open MPI
mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.6

Comment: `printf()` typically buffers IO and flush it when there is a `\n`. try `fflush(stdout);` after `printf()` without `\n`.